# Date format Issue while reading with Aspose

Tags: java, excel, date, date-formatting, aspose-cells

I want to read dates from .xlsx file , I am using Aspose to read the date  value from the column,
But the output date value i got was in a different date format, Following are the dates  needed
in output

input dates:

14-03-2022

14-03-2022

14-03-2022

11-03-2022

11-03-2022

11-03-2022

10-03-2022

10-03-2022

10-03-2022

10-03-2022

Observed output date value (read values):

14-03-2022

14-03-2022

14-03-2022

03-11-2022

03-11-2022

03-11-2022

03-10-2022

03-10-2022

03-10-2022

03-10-2022

I need the dates as in the form of input dates as output, but the output am getting in different form , you can see first three dates are in correct format rest of all are in wrong format.

Code:

```
private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatIn = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatConv = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
      
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        rowLoop:

        for (int j = 5; j < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()-1; j++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(j);
            if (row != null) {
                AxisPojo axisPayPojo = new AxisPojo();
                Iterator<Cell> it = row.cellIterator();
                int k = 0;
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Cell ce = it.next();
                    k = ce.getColumnIndex();
                    CellType cellType = ce.getCellTypeEnum();
                    if(k==0) {

                            if (cellType == CellType.STRING || cellType == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                                ce.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
                              
                                    Date date = simpleDateFormatIn.parse(ce.toString());
                                    String out = simpleDateFormatConv.format(date);
                                    axisPayPojo.setDate(out);
                           }
```

Is there any possible solution for this?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am sorry, I don’t get what you mean. Do you want `14-03-2022` stay the same in the output but `11-03-2022` switched around to `03-11-2022`? In which cases do you want which? Also, does your code already give you what you want, and if not, what does it do instead?

Comment: I need the dates as in the form of  input dates as output, but the output am getting in different form , you can see first three dates are in correct format rest of all are in wrong format

Comment: Now it’s clear, thank you. The bug is hardly in the code that you have posted. So probably elsewhere. Could it be that you need to format the cells in Excel?

Comment: You said at the start of your question that you are using Aspose API... "I am using Aspose to read the date value from the column" but your code does not suggest that you are using Aspose.Cells for Java.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.